# df apply function in loop overrides prior values

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, apply

so my df looks like this:

```
                 x            y      group
0                53           10     csv1
1                53           10     csv1
2                48           9      csv0
3                48           9      csv0
4                48           9      csv0
...              ...          ...    ...
```

I have some files that are depending on the group name and want to use them in a function besides the x and y value.

what I am doing so far is the following:

```
dfGrouped = df.groupby('group') #group the dataframe
df['newcol'] = np.nan #crete new empty col

#use for loop to load file depending on group, note the file is very large, thats why I want to load it only once per group
for name, group in groupHashed:
    file = open(name+'.txt')
    #open the file
    df['newcol'] = df[df['group'] == name].apply(lambda row: newValueFromFile(row.x,row.y, file), axis=1)
```

It seemed to work at first, unfortunately, newcol only holds the value of the last loop and seems to override the values created earlier with nan. Somebody any idea?

Answer (score 0):

instead of file = open, use

```
with open('filename.txt', 'a') as file:
```

and then for the lambda expression file.write...

The 'a' in the opening tells it should append the data to the existing.
I guess currently you are overwriting the content of the file.
'`with open()`' also takes care for the automatic closing after you're done with the file.

Comment: sorry, it seems that my describtion was a little bit unclear. The actual problem is created by the following line:  df['newcol'] = df[df['group'] == name].apply(lambda row: newValueFromFile(row.x,row.y, file), axis=1)
The new value in the dataframe col newcol are nan...